# How to Loop Into jQuery UI Restricted DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to restrict the jQuery UI DatePicker to Current year only and so far it is working fine at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/kpx6gc58/)

I used the following code to do the job

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(2013, 12, 1),
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    maxDate: new Date(2014, 11, 31)
});
```

As you can see the Previous and Next buttons disable at January (Previous Click) and December (Next click) but just wondering if there is a way to create a circular action(re start) at the end or beginning

like

> ...<-October <-November <-December <-January -> .... ->November
> ->December->January -> Feb...>

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you try with just jQuery UI DatePicker library,I thin is not possible, but if you really need that function you can create you own control based on jQuery UI DatePicker or use another plugin like [this plugin](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)